# How to set proper PATH for proc_open

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
$process = proc_open(sprintf('node "%s"', $tmpfile), $desc, $pipes);
```

Which produces

```
sh: node: command not found
```

I tried to set `$PATH` in `httpd.conf` with `SetEnv`, then echo it using `getenv('PATH')`. The output actually contains the path to node.

I was able to [pass](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) the variable to `proc_open`, but I'd like to avoid that because it's someone else's code.

Is there a way for me to give it the correct path?

I am running XAMPP 1.8.2 for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the $pipes you can assign the CWD. You should pass it here. In terms of setting the cwd with the php.ini file, I don't think this is possible.

You should be able to do the following:

```
$process = proc_open(sprintf('node "%s"', $tmpfile), $desc, $pipes, __DIR__);
```

Providing the "node" executable is in the same directory. Alternatively you could move "node" to

```
echo getcwd();
```

Although this is a bit messy usually.

Edit:
You should also be able to get away with using an alias or symlink to the cwd

Comment: Thanks for the idea about symbolic link. This code runs fine on the server, just that I wanted to get a local version without changing the code.

Answer (score 4):

proc_open lets you pass environment variable into it.  This is probably the easiest to get node if the path of your PHP spawned process.

```
$env = array(
    'PATH' => '/usr/local/bin' //Path to node bin dir
);

$process = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes, __DIR__, $env);
```